# Blur effect in iOS which ignores accessibilty ("reduce transparency" option)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, accessibility, uivisualeffectview

I have a blurred view which overlays other views.

`UIVisualEffectView` is not appropriate because it is disabled when user sets `Accessibility >> Reduce transparency`.

Could you suggest how to show this blur always independently from the device settings? Both `UIVisualEffectView` and custom control are applicable. And both swift and objC solutions are applicable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prevent Acessibility from applying to a view by using:

```
self.accessibilityElementsHidden = YES;
```

This being said, you shouldn't go against Human Interface Guidelines. There is a good reason why accessibility features exist.

[Human Interface Guidelines - Accessibility](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/interaction/accessibility/)

Here are some excerpts from Apple's [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/2016-06-13/#user-interface) to explain.

> 10.1 Apps must comply with all terms and conditions explained in the Apple iOS Human Interface Guidelines
>
> 10.3 Apps that do not use system provided items, such as buttons and icons, correctly and as described in the Apple iOS Human Interface Guidelines may be rejected

Comment: This doesn't appear to affect UIVisualEffectView.